# Change bootstrap 3 arrow tooltip width

Tags: css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I´m having an issue with Bootstrap 3 tooltip, I want to change the arrow position.

I changed the class

```
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow
{
    border-right-color: #8BA6D5;
    border-width: 40px;
}
```

**- Result:**

[image: Current]

What i want:

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the HTML and CSS that is creating the arrow?

Comment: @dmikester1 It´s the bootstrap class `.tooltip-arrow`

Comment: Can you provide us jsfiddle example to help you?

Comment: jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/otxL8v5s/) @Slasher

Comment: @GerardoRodriguez Don't forget to mark it as answer if my solution helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**: https://jsfiddle.net/otxL8v5s/7/

You have to change **negative** `margin` of tooltip arrow.

```
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow
    {
        border-right-color: #8BA6D5;
        border-width: 40px;
        margin-left: -35px;
        margin-top: -39px;
    }
```

You can move this arrow more to the left if you *incerase negative* `margin-left`.