# Is there any way to increase the size of the arrow in React Tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-tooltip

I have gone through the official documentation, and haven't found how to increase the react tooltip arrow size.

```
<span className="icon margin-10-right txtSize20 txtBlue icon_profile-menu icon-tool" 
data-tip={`<p>HTML</p>`}
data-for={data._id} data-place="right" data-effect="solid" data-type="light" data-text-color="black" data-html={true} data-class="tooltip2">
</span> 
<ReactTooltip className="custom-tool" html={true} multiline={false}  scrollHide={false} id={data._id}/>
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104196/change-bootstrap-3-arrow-tooltip-width

Comment: I am using custom classes and the React-Tooltip library, not bootstrap. That wont work.

Answer (score 0):

The library doesn't support that. However, you can do the following workaround:

- add `uuid = "uuid-for-tooltip-arrow"` as a property for `ReactTooltip`. For example:

```
...
<ReactTooltip uuid = "uuid-for-tooltip-arrow" className="custom-tool" .../>
```

- add the following CSS code:

```css
.uuid-for-tooltip-arrow.place-top::after {
  bottom: -<new-height>px !important;
  border-top-width: <new-height>px !important;
}
```

where `<new-height>` is a number representing the new height in pixels. E.g. if you want to double the height, it's going to be `12`, resulting in

```css
.uuid-for-tooltip-arrow.place-top::after {
  bottom: -12px !important;
  border-top-width: 12px !important;
}
```

Also note that you have to change `place-top` to the appropriate direction if the tooltip is not on the top. So if you set `place = "left"`, then you have to add the following CSS:

```css
.uuid-for-tooltip-arrow.place-left::after {
  bottom: -12px !important;
  border-top-width: 12px !important;
}
```